# how to listen for new event on server

Tags: php, android, server

I need to create a Listener for new events on server in android.
I was using a request to the server cyclically for new events before.

But this is not a suitable way because of performances and internet traffic.
Another way could be using a listener, but I don't know **HOW TO** ?

Please guide me!

Comment: It's March already..

Comment: @ali - I am glad my answer is useful..U could upvote it so the answer lookers will be able to know worth of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polling the server may drain the battery

You can take advantage of *Google Cloud Messaging* for Android

> Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) for Android is a service that allows you
>   to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device,
>   and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection. The
>   GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery
>   to the target Android application running on the target device, and it
>   is completely free.

It will work on Android >= 2.2 (on phones that have the Play Store)

Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to official documentation

Here is a sample php code that sends push notification

```
<?php
function sendPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {

    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'AIzaSyCjctNK2valabAWL7rWUTcoRA-UAXI_3ro');

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    echo json_encode($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false)
        die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;

}
?>
```

Here is a [good article](http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Push-Notification-Android/) on android push notifications